# Sumifs between two values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to solve the below written formula:

```
=SUMIFS(AE9:AE17,S8:S17,">=1.0",S8:S17,"<=1.15")
```

it returns #VALUE! Error.

`AE9:AE17` is the sum range

I couldn't find the solution online. Anyone out there can help?

Comment: all ranges in the criteria must be the same size and shape.  `AE9:AE17` is not the same size and shape as `S8:S17`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **sum** range and the **criteria** range in formula are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your Formula should be written like this:

```
=SUMIFS(AE9:AE17,S9:S17,">=1.0",S9:S17,"<=1.15")
```

**Note:** The problem with your formula was Mismatch of SUM & CRITERIA range, as mentioned by Lee also.